# Optimise matrix inversion in python for impedance calculation

Tags: impedance, python, matrix

To get the impedance profile for a circuit, I am using its admittance (G) and capacitance (C) matrices.

I am using python to compute impedance profile at different frequencies but the issue is that I need to invert matrix to get impedance from admittance and this turns out to be a very expensive operation in a loop.

For a large matrix (1000*1000) I have, inverting a matrix using numpy linalg.inv needs approx 1 second and therefore for a loop running 10^6 iterations below, I get unreasonably large execution time.

Need some guidance how can I optimise this or if there's anyway to bypass matrix inversion and yet get the impedance matrix.

Please find below pseudo code.

```
    A = j*2*3.14*C #j 2pi C to create susceptance matrix when multiplied by freq below.
    for freq in range (1, 100000000, 100):
            Y = G + A * freq #admittance matrix
            Z = np.linalg.inv(Y) #inverse the matrix to get impedance matrix
            output[freq] = Z
```

I have already tried numpy linalg.solve instead of using inversion. But the execution time remains unreasonably large.
Please help.

Comment: Can you explain how the manipulation of matrix mathematics is an exclusive discipline within the umbrella of EE?

Comment: I suspect the matrices will be sparse. Check out sparse solvers.